# Can a PostgreSQL stored procedure return multiple rows

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-11

I can create a procedure to return multiple values:

```
create or replace procedure hello(inout a text, inout b integer)
as $$
begin
    a := 'foo';
    b := 123;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

And call it from psql like so:

```
# call hello1('a', 1);
  a  |  b  
-----+-----
 foo | 123
(1 row)
```

Is there a way to return multiple rows, like you can with functions? Functions that do that have a certain `returns ...` clause, but there is no `returns` clause with procedures.

Comment: What's wrong with using a function? That is the best solution for that problem

Comment: I'd like to control transactions, which is not possible inside functions.

Comment: No, but you could aggregate your result and sneak it out in a json or array parameter. Other techniques, such as returning a cursor or creating a temporary table rely on the existence of a transaction before the call, which isn't allowed if you want to perform transaction manipulation in your procedure.